# Save/Load User Inputs from Scripted GUI in ExtendScript?

Tags: extendscript

I'm creating a very simple GUI in ExtendScript and I'd like to know how to save and open any user inputs from the "edittext" boxes that I've created. How would I be able to add a "file>save" and "file>open" menu to save and retrieve any user inputs?

```
//GUI Design
var myWin = new Window ("palette", "EditTextTest", undefined);
myWin.orientation = "row";

var groupOne = myWin.add("group", undefined, "GroupOne");
groupOne.orientation = "column";
groupOne.add("statictext", undefined, "Player 01 Name");
var etOne = groupOne.add("edittext", undefined, "");
etOne .characters = 10;
groupOne.add("statictext", undefined, "Player 02 Name");
var etTwo = groupOne.add("edittext", undefined, "");
etTwo .characters = 10;
groupOne.add("statictext", undefined, "Player 03 Name");
var etThree = groupOne.add("edittext", undefined, "");
etThree .characters = 10;
groupOne.add("statictext", undefined, "Player 04 Name");
var etFour = groupOne.add("edittext", undefined, "");
etFour .characters = 10;
groupOne.add("statictext", undefined, "Player 05 Name");
var etFive = groupOne.add("edittext", undefined, "");
etFive .characters = 10;

myWin.center();
myWin.show();
```

Comment: I think if you show some code that you have tried, that the trolls won't downvote you like that without saying why.  It helps if you make your title simpler, and then elaborate in the question.  If you rewrite things, I'll vote you back up.

Comment: Thanks BGM!  Sorry, I'm completely new to this!  I tried to add an image as well, but I'm unable to without 10 reputation points.

Comment: Take a look into Peter Kahrels Script UI guide on how to build GUIs http://www.kahrel.plus.com/indesign/scriptui.html and take a look into this code on how to read write files https://github.com/fabiantheblind/extendscript/wiki/Create-And-Read-Files

Comment: Andy, don't worry - you'll get used to it. It is very much worth it, so don't lose heart if your points are low.  The real value is getting your questions answered.

Answer (score 2):

If you are developing for AE, you can use the following to store and retrieve values in app's native preference file:

```
app.settings.haveSetting("myScriptPrefCategory", "myControl");     //Check for saved pref value
app.settings.saveSetting("myScriptPrefCategory", "myControl", "controlValue");     //Saves a pref value
app.settings.getSetting("myScriptPrefCategory", "myControl");     //Retrieves a pref value
```

I learned this from David Torno.  [See this forum thread](http://forums.adobe.com/message/5666562#5666562) at the AE Scripting Forums.

Upon initialization of your code,  you can lookup the preference that you've created, then setup your UI to reflect the values stored in that preference file.